# mailgun eu domain (https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain) is return undefined response

Tags: sendmail, mailgun

I am trying to send an email using my custom eu domain.
When I send an email although the status is 200 but I am getting `body` as undefined, which should be an object of message id and additional to other properties.
If you could help will be great, thank.
This is my code:

```
 const mailGunConfig = require("mailgun-js")({
  apiKey: process.env.MAIL_GUN_API_KEY,
  domain: https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.org,
 });

 const data = {
    from: userEmail,
    to: process.env.MY_EMAIL,
    subject,
    html: `some html contents`,
  };

 mailGunConfig.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer, it was about the domain, I split it to host and domain like this:

```
 const mailGunConfig = require("mailgun-js")({
  apiKey: process.env.MAIL_GUN_API_KEY,
  domain: mydomain.org,
  host: "api.eu.mailgun.net"
 });
```

Instead of this:

```
 const mailGunConfig = require("mailgun-js")({
  apiKey: process.env.MAIL_GUN_API_KEY,
  domain: https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mydomain.org,
 });
```